# ¿Cómo mostrar "algo" cuando la consulta debido a la condición no nos retorna nada?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, postgresql, mysql-workbench

Mi query de prueba es el siguiente:

select 'No hay data' as 'Data' from dual where 1=2;

Esto es lo que me arroja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que necesito es que salga de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: eso, basicamente, no es sql.. workbench es la ide para que vos trabajes tus consultas e interactues con la DB, para desarrollo y pruebas.. esto que pedis, no tiene nada que ver con SQL.. podrias hacerlo? si, con un store procedure, o querys de querys.. tiene sentido? no, porque esas cosas las resuelve el front de tu aplicacion, no la DB...

Comment: @gbianchi 
Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que la consulta me retorne algo aunque no se cumpla la condición.
Modifique el query para hacerlo mas entendible.

Comment: no hay registros a mostrar cuando no hay datos.. sql no es magico.. si no hay datos, tu count de esa consulta da 0 y ahi si podrias mostrar algo.. pero no en sql... sql no es para esto!ç

Comment: Concuerdo con Gbianchi, el como el cliente ve los datos, está a cargo del cliente. Sql solo debería encargarse de enviar los datos requeridos.

Comment: Si se puede chicos... ya lo logré...

select 'No hay data' as 'Data' from dual where 1=2 HAVING count(*)=0;

La funcion having count(*)=0; te indica si la consulta no tiene registros, es decir en mi query aunque no hayan registros permitirá mostrar la columna recién creada en la misma consulta.

Comment: Pon la respuesta ya que puede servir a otros